# Changed Robocopy script from network share to local share and it stopped logging

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

Original **working** code that copied files from one server to another and logged the activity

- Line 1: `net use Y: "\\192.168.100.94\SQL_Backups"`
- Line 2: `net use Z: "\\192.168.100.94\SQL_Backups_Logs"`
- Line 3: `set sourcepath=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup`
- Line 4: `set destinationpath=Y:`
- Line 5: `set logpath=Z:`
- Line 6: `set filename=SQL_Backup_Job_%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%#%time::=-%.txt`
- Line 7: `robocopy "%sourcepath%" "%destinationpath%" /MIR /V /ETA /R:0 /W:0 /COPYALL /LOG:"%logpath%%filename%" /NP`

I then attached a USB drive to the source server and removed lines 1 & 2

Then changed lines 4 & 5 to the following...

- Line 4: `set destinationpath=E:\PrimaryServerBackup\SQL_Backups`
- Line 5: `set logpath=E:\PrimaryServerBackup\SQL_Backups_Logs`

Now the copying still works, but it **no longer logs the activity** - the log file isn't even created

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, I had to enter a backslash at the end of line 5

`Line 5: set logpath=E:\PrimaryServerBackup\SQL_Backups_Logs\`

It wasn't required when I copied to a network share, but copying locally seems to require it.